# Python: equivalent of input using sys.stdin

Tags: python, dependency-injection, python-3.x, mocking, stdin

I want to test some (python 3) code that directly uses the `print` and `input` functions.  As I understand it, the easiest way to do this is by dependency injection: modifying the code so that it takes input and output streams as arguments, using `sys.stdin` and `sys.stdout` by default and passing in mock objects during testing.  It's obvious what to do with `print` calls:

```
print(text)
#replaced with...
print(text, file=output_stream)
```

However, `input` doesn't have arguments for input and output streams.  Does the following code correctly reproduce its behaviour?

```
text = input(prompt)
#replaced with...
print(prompt, file=output_stream, end='')
text = input_stream.readline()[:-1]
```

I had a look at the implementation of `input`, and it does quite a lot of magic, calling `sys.stdin.fileno` and examining `sys.stdin.encoding` and `sys.stdin.errors` rather than calling any of the `read*` methods - I wouldn't know where to start with mocking those.

Comment: in addition it may be using the GNU readline library as well. I actually never use `input`, so that makes it easier for me.

Comment: What's the specific use case?

Comment: @JonClements: it's just a simple front-end that asks the user to specify a few options.  Thinking about it, it might be easier just to accept a list of answers as an optional argument, but I'd still be interested to know if there is an easy way of duplicating `input`'s behaviour.

Comment: this thread may be useful  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13143218/how-do-i-avoid-processing-an-empty-stdin-with-python/13143479#13143479

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`input()` only does the magic you mentioned when `stdin` and `stdout` are not altered, because only then it can use things like the readline library. If you replace them with something else (real-files or not) it comes down to this code:

```
/* Fallback if we're not interactive */
if (promptarg != NULL) {
    if (PyFile_WriteObject(promptarg, fout, Py_PRINT_RAW) != 0)
         return NULL;
}
tmp = _PyObject_CallMethodId(fout, &PyId_flush, "");
if (tmp == NULL)
    PyErr_Clear();
else
    Py_DECREF(tmp);
return PyFile_GetLine(fin, -1);
```

Where `PyFile_GetLine` [calls the `readline`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/47943fe516ec/Objects/fileobject.c#l50) method. Thus mocking `sys.std*` will work.

It's recomended you do this with `try: finally:`, a context processor or the `mock` module, so that the outputs are restored even if the code you are testing fails with exceptions:

```
from unittest.mock import patch
from io import StringIO

with patch("sys.stdin", StringIO("FOO")), patch("sys.stdout", new_callable=StringIO) as mocked_out:
    x = input()
    print("Read:", x)

assert mocked_out.getvalue() == "Read: FOO\n"
```

Answer (score 7):

If you assign a file-like object to `sys.stdin` Python's `input` function will use it instead of the standard input. But remember to reassign `sys.stdin` back to the standard input after you're done with it. The same trick applies to `sys.stdout`. You can do something like this:

```
original_stdin = sys.stdin
sys.stdin = open('inputfile.txt', 'r')

original_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = open('outputfile.txt', 'w')

response = input('say hi: ')
print(response)

sys.stdin = original_stdin
sys.stdout = original_stdout
```

These two lines

```
response = input('say hi: ')
print(response)
```

will use specified files (`inputfile.txt` and `outputfile.txt`) instead of the standard input and standard output.

UPDATE: If you don't want to deal with physical files take a look at `io` module. It provides `io.StringIO` class which allows you to perform in-memory text stream operations.

```
original_stdin = sys.stdin
sys.stdin = io.StringIO('input string')

original_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = io.StringIO()

response = input('say hi: ')
print(response)

output = sys.stdout.getvalue()

sys.stdin = original_stdin
sys.stdout = original_stdout

print(output)
```

Comment: A "file-like object" is a technical term with a [defined meaning](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-file-like-object) in Python.  For this to properly work with `input()`, you will probably need a real file object, backed by a real OS file.  I wouldn't expect that e.g. `io.StringIO` works in this context.

Comment: I've just tried it with `io.StringIO` and it actually works. I'll update my answer with the code that works with `io.StringIO`.

Comment: I did not try.  My guess was based on the fact that according to the OP the implementation of `input()` uses the `fileno` attribute, which only makes sense for OS files.