# I want to use stdin in a pytest test

Tags: python, pytest

The PyTest documentation states that stdin is redirected to null as no-one will want to do interactive testing in a batch test context. This is true, but interactive is not the only use of stdin. I want to test code that uses stdin just as it would use any other file. I am happy with stdout and sterr being captured but how to actually have stdin connected to an io.StringIO object say in a PyTest conformant way?

Comment: Just mock stdin in those tests.

Comment: You've almost answered your own question. You could refactor your code to use something like `io.StringIO` instead of referencing stdin directly, in order to pass a mocked object during testing while being able to handle stdin during "real" usage.

Comment: See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13238566/python-equivalent-of-input-using-sys-stdin

Comment: I tried:

`def test_main_with_empty_list_argument():
    with patch(sys.stdin, io.StringIO('')):
        wc.main([])`

but it gives:

`E           AttributeError: 'DontReadFromInput' object has no attribute 'rsplit'`

Comment: OK, stupid error, I failed to put the sys.stdin as a string. :-(

Answer (score 52):

You can [monkeypatch it](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/monkeypatch.html):

```
def test_method(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr('sys.stdin', io.StringIO('my input'))
    # test code
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could run your script as a `subprocess`? In Python 3.6:

```
import subprocess

def test_a_repl_session():
    comlist = ['./executable_script.py']
    script = b'input\nlines\n\n'
    res = subprocess.run(comlist, input=script,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    assert res.returncode == 0
    assert res.stdout
    assert res.stderr == b''
```

Comment: This works and was what I was doing for awhile until I needed coverage reports. Nothing in the subprocess counts for that. :(

Comment: > _"Nothing in the subprocess counts for [coverage]."_ ohwwww, that's whyy. Yeah, i was using `subprocess.run`, had installed `pytest-cov` too; but it wasn't showing up. i always wondered why. thanks a lottt for sharing. it means i will _have to_ migrate to making the `package` inclusive or `modue` runnable too.