# How to test a script which has no user functions but uses the built-in input function?

Tags: python

Given the script **rectangle.py**
How can I test the script as is.
I cannot figure out how to test it in doctest, unittest, or pytest as is.
My question is essentially, how can a test respond to the input prompt during a test?

```
"""
Compute the area of a rectangle.
"""
width = int(input("Enter the width: "))
height = int(input("Enter the height: "))
area = width * height
print (f"The area is {area}.")
```

Example of testing by running the script multiple times.

```
C:\TestingDoctest>py rectangle.py
Enter the width: 9
Enter the height: 8
The area is 72.

C:\TestingDoctest>py rectangle.py
Enter the width: 6
Enter the height: 7
The area is 42.

C:\TestingDoctest>py rectangle.py
Enter the width: 8
Enter the height: 9
The area is 72.

C:\TestingDoctest>py rectangle.py
Enter the width: 8.8
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\TestingDoctest\rectangle.py", line 1, in <module>
    width = int(input("Enter the width: "))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '8.8'

C:\TestingDoctest>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want to use stdin in a pytest test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38723140/i-want-to-use-stdin-in-a-pytest-test)

Comment: Is there are reason you dont put it in a function?

Comment: The reason I do not put in a function is I will not be testing my code. I will be having multiple students submitting code per assignment. I am just starting to look at the feasibility of testing their code. I see many potential issues. Early in the class, they will not be aware of user functions.
I will look into the link.

Comment: @SuperStormer I will look into the suggested link further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how you would test this without it being wrapped in a function. However simply wrapping it all in a function like

**chris.py**

```py
def rectangle_area():
    """
    Compute the area of a rectangle.
    """
    width = int(input("Enter the width: "))
    height = int(input("Enter the height: "))
    area = width * height
    print(f"The area is {area}.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    rectangle_area()
```

I would test it by mocking the input function and using side affect to pass in the values. then using capf to capture the output of the print. I am using the module `pytest-mock` here but similar could be acheived with unittest and its mock methods.

**test_chris.py**

```py
from chris import rectangle_area
import pytest

def test_rectangle_area_valid_string_ints(mocker, capfd):
    test_input = mocker.patch("chris.input")
    test_input.side_effect = ("5", "10")
    rectangle_area()
    out, err = capfd.readouterr()
    assert out == f"The area is 50.\n"

def test_rectange_area_invalid_strings(mocker):
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        test_input = mocker.patch("chris.input")
        test_input.side_effect = ("10.5", "10")
        rectangle_area()
```

I have added two test functions, one to check valid ints return the expected output, and one to check none valid ints raise a ValueError.

**OUTPUT**

```
plugins: Faker-8.1.2, mock-3.6.1
collected 2 items                                                                                                                                      

test_chris.py::test_rectangle_area_valid_string_ints PASSED                                                                                     [ 50%]
test_chris.py::test_rectange_area_invalid_strings PASSED                                                                                         [100%]

================================================================== 2 passed in 0.17s ==================================================================
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I will be reviewing it and respond further.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I learned something new. Based on the comments and code provided, I think I should try an alternative approach. 
Some combination of parsing the file to verify it meets the assignment specification and testing.
Perhaps wrap the student code in a function and using a decorator.